# Having Problem with Making List of Concentrations in Python

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and have a question about turning a list of numbers to a list with units.

For example I can have an array of concentrations C = [1, 2, 3, 4], but what can I do to make a new list so that each value has a unit after it (e.g. C_list = [1M, 2M, 3M, 4M])

I tried to make the following code, but it instead return the same number
(e.g. C_list is [ 2M, 2M, 2M, 2M] instead of [1M, 2M, 3M, 4M]):

```
S0 = [0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 1.4, 1.8]#initial substrate concentration
S0_Legend = np.empty(len(S0),dtype='S10')    
for i in S0:
    a=str(i)+'M'
    for x in range(len(S0)):
          S0_Legend[x] = a
print(S0_Legend)
```

Any and all help would break greatly appreciated!

Comment: The reason your logic doesn't work is because with *each* of the `i` values, it sets *every* value of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better keep it simple, just add your unit as you do in your code `str(i)+'M'`, and then append each element to new list:

```
S0 = [0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 1.4, 1.8]
S0_Legend = []
for i in S0:
    S0_Legend.append(str(i)+'M') 
print(S0_Legend)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
S0 = [0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 1.4, 1.8]

print([str(x) + 'M' for x in S0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['0.3M', '0.7M', '1.0M', '1.4M', '1.8M']
```